# Complex number with magnitude equality

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

I am stucked in this exercise:

Find the values of $a∈R^-$ such that $|2a−ai|=a+2$. Note $R^−=\{x∈R/x≤0\}$

I tried to operate the magnitude and I came up with this:
$5a^2=a+2$ but I cannot get any correct solution and I do not know how to continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, $a \in R^{-} \implies |a|=-a$. Second, $|2a-ai|=|a(2-i)|=|a||2-i|=-a\sqrt{5}$. Last,
$$|2a-ai|=a+2 \implies \sqrt{5}a+a+2 = 0 \implies a = -\frac{2}{1+\sqrt{5}}.$$

Comment: Why do you put $-a\sqrt5$?

Comment: $a \leq 0$ as the question says

Comment: @Evoked $|2-i|=\sqrt{2^2+1^2}=\sqrt{5}$, and $a \le 0 \implies |a|=-a$.

Comment: Thank you! @MathLover

Comment: And the golden ratio appears :)